# ¿Cómo asignar a una variable el valor de una promesa?

Tags: javascript, poo, promesas, async-await, async

Quisiera saber como hacer una función que retorne lo que resuelve una promesa y luego eso asignarserlo a una variable, ejemplo:

```javascript
let Get = async () =>{
  try{
    let res = await 
    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/pikachu');
    let data = await res.json();
    let obj = {
      img : data.sprites.front_default,
      habilidad: data.abilities[0]
    }
    return obj;
  }
  catch(err){
    throw ("ha ocurrido un error" + err);
  }
}
```

```javascript
var nueva = Get();
console.log(nueva);
```

Comment: Y ¿cuál es el problema en este momento? ¿Te tira errores la llamada a `Get()`? El segundo bloque de código no te va a imprimir el resultado, la primera línea es async pero el `console.log()` no, y va a imprimir la variable antes de que sea asignada.

Comment: y como pudiese hacer para asignarle el valor que retorna esa función asincrona a la variable?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes 2 opciones:

1. Usar `.then` en `Get()`
2. Llamar a `Get()` desde una función `async` y usar `await`.

### Opción 1:

```js
let Get = async () =>{
  try{
    let res = await 
    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/pikachu');
    let data = await res.json();
    let obj = {
      img : data.sprites.front_default,
      habilidad: data.abilities[0]
    }
    return obj;
  }
  catch(err){
    throw ("ha ocurrido un error" + err);
  }
}
Get().then(nueva => console.log(nueva));
```

### Opción 2

```js
let Get = async () =>{
  try{
    let res = await 
    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/pikachu');
    let data = await res.json();
    let obj = {
      img : data.sprites.front_default,
      habilidad: data.abilities[0]
    }
    return obj;
  }
  catch(err){
    throw ("ha ocurrido un error" + err);
  }
}

async function foo() {
  let nueva = await Get();
  console.log(nueva);
}

foo();
```

Puedes leer más información sobre [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) y [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).